# Syncing Outlook delegate calendar on Galaxy S6 Lollipop 5.1

Tags: microsoft-outlook, android, calendar, activesync

So I need to sync a user's calendar to their Galaxy S6's Calendar/Planner they are on the latest OS (Lollipop 5.1), I can't seem to find a way that will allow me to sync their outlook calendar and their boss's calendar to which they have full delegate access.

Is anyone aware of any solution to this? This is in a corporate environment so if the solution is long-winded or very complicated it won't be viable as the user's setup their emails on their phones.

The user can see their calendar fine it's just the delegated calendar that I can't seem to find/sync.

I've tried downloading the Outlook App, multiple calendar apps etc

Answer (score 0):

The only accounts (email - other accounts like Facebook can natively sync this information over) that will sync over contacts and calendar natively are Google (gmail account) and Exchange accounts. Here are a few basic guides that Samsung has for getting that information over:

Calendar:
http://www.samsung.com/us/support/faq/FAQ00059165/81096/SGH-I337ZKZAIO

There is also an option to sync individual folders, and just below that is an option to notify. I think it's under your account settings, kinda a weird place.

What about root access? (see http://wyckedroot.com/) Did you try it yet? Maybe there's an app around that requires SuperUser access that can sort your problems out?